# Change numeric values in rows of CSV if string in same row has certain value

Tags: python, pandas, bash, csv, awk

I have a ***csv*** that looks like below with up to ***15000 lines***.
The numeric values of `Start` and `End` are between 0 and 300.
I am looking for a way to parse through the file, search for rows starting with `white`, then check the `Start` value and the `End` value of this row with the following conditions:

1. if the value ≤ 150 then add 150
2. if the value is > 150 then subtract 150

Finally, overwrite the source file with the edits.
I am looking for a way to realize that with bash or python.
Any help is much appreciated!

Raw Data:

```
Color, Start, End
white, 0, 1, 
black, 23, 150, 
black, 150, 24, 
white, 24, 152, 
black, 152, 25, 
black, 25, 154, 
black, 154, 81, 
white, 99, 220,
...
```

Final Data:

```
Color, Start, End
white, 150, 151, 
black, 23, 150, 
black, 150, 24, 
white, 174, 2, 
black, 152, 25, 
black, 25, 154, 
black, 154, 81, 
white, 249, 70,
...
```

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. What did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect job for `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=', ' '$1=="white" {for(i=2;i<=3;i++) if($i<=150) $i+=150; else $i-=150} 1' file.csv
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks a lot!
I added a ```> output.csv``` to the end of the command to write the results in a file

Answer (score 0):

Python code that does it:

*note: If you run it twice all values will be reset, except 0, which will be 300.*

```
f = open("colors.csv", "r")
lines = f.read().split("\n")
f.close()
output = ""
for l in lines:
    parts = l.split(",")
    if len(parts) >= 3 and parts[0] == "white":
        if int(parts[1]) > 150:
            parts[1] = str(int(parts[1]) - 150)
        else:
            parts[1] = str(int(parts[1]) + 150)
        if int(parts[2]) > 150:
            parts[2] = str(int(parts[2]) - 150)
        else:
            parts[2] = str(int(parts[2]) + 150)
        output += (parts[0] + ", " + parts[1] + ", " + parts[2] + ",\n")
    else:
        output += (l + "\n")
f = open("colors.csv", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Comment: If it worked you should mark it as accepted answer (or mark the awk one, which was more elegant).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *, *"; OFS=", "; n=150} $1=="white"{ for (i=2; i<NF; i++) $i+=($i>n ? -n : n) } 1' file
Color, Start, End
white, 150, 151,
black, 23, 150,
black, 150, 24,
white, 174, 2,
black, 152, 25,
black, 25, 154,
black, 154, 81,
white, 249, 70,
```